# How do the different species understand each other?

Tags: stargate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does everyone on almost every planet in the Pegasus Galaxy speak English?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2743/why-does-everyone-on-almost-every-planet-in-the-pegasus-galaxy-speak-english)

Why do all the species in the Stargate universe speak English? I know that humans were spread across the universe but what about the other species they meet. Do they have some sort of universal translator or something?

Comment: Duplicate of [this questino](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2743/why-does-everyone-on-almost-every-planet-in-the-pegasus-galaxy-speak-english) and [this closed question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10479/english-in-stargate).

Comment: @TangoOversway I would tend to disagree that this is a Duplicate of the first thread and for that I would down grade you for it if it was an answer, but the second one you are right it is a Duplicate. But would it not of been more constructive to give the answer link that that thread is a duplicate of?

Comment: Closing duplicates is how things are done in the StackExchange universe.  Each time we ask a question, we are expected to search the site to see if that question has already been answered.  Even if the exact question itself is not posted, but there is still an answer given that would answer the new question, it's a duplicate.  Sometimes it's hard to keep it straight.  I've asked more questions on SF&F than anyone else, and even I end up asking duplicates because I used the wrong search terms.

Comment: @TangoOversway OK that sounds fair. I didn't mean for it to sound offensive if you took it that why. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote one of the producers of the series, [Joseph Mallozzi](http://josephmallozzi.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/may-27-2011-getting-the-book-of-the-month-club-back-on-track-more-dark-matter-designs/):

> enectrixx also writes: “Do you have any explanation as to why all the
>   alien cultures (except the Goa’uld and a few others) speak fluent
>   modern english?”
>
> Answer: In my mind, every time a traveller stepped through the gate,
>   they were reassembled on the other side with the **benefit of translator
>   nanites** that allowed them to not only understand but be understood in
>   turn.  Some languages (like the goa’uld tongue) proved resistant to
>   the technology.

(my emphasis)

Comment: Good answer but how would you explain if there world was taken over by another species that lets say went by ship?

Comment: @mattInman - I'm not explaining, I'm telling you what one of the producers of Stargate SG-1 said he felt was the answer =) Without knowing what the example you're referring to is specifically, I can't answer that - but that'd be a different question anyway =)